# How to calculate whistle parameters for given frequency?

Tags: acoustics

I would like to build powerful and yet cheap whistle. So I was thinking about buying vuvuzela and turning it to high-pitch whistle.

However I have to make a whistle for precisely given frequency -- so the question is how to calculate the placement and size of the top hole, and the size of intake hole assuming I don't have to modify the out flow hole.

**[on hold]** Could someone in such case simply transfer the question? It is no point asking duplicate question on twin forum.

Comment: I don't understand what the 'on hold' edit means. Transfer the question to where? What twin forum?

Comment: @KyleKanos, "engineering" as the "put on hold" description explains. For me it is still physics, because I don't ask how to cut something but how to calculate, but it is better to have open question on Eng. than closed here.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, that's bloody complicated if you would go to the details. Generally, the initial guess can be made from this formula:

$$
f = St\frac{U}{d}
$$

where $U$ is the flow speed, $d$ is distance between the edge (labium) of the whistle and a narrow canal from which the air goes. Constant $St$ is called [Strouhal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strouhal_number) and for these kind of systems is usually:

$$
St=0.185
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This is interesting, it seems the frequency does not depend on the total length of the whistle.

Comment: Strictly speaking: that's the frequency of the so called edge tones - that'll provide the excitation mechanism. The closer is that to the natural frequency of the whistle body, the better - the body will do the amplification and it is length etc. dependent.